# Unable to upload multipart file in karate, Required request part '' not present

Tags: karate

[ActualAPIRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RwPu.png)        [OutputFromKarate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS7J8.png)

Trying to upload a json file for an api using karate. Since  api takes multipart input i am passing multipart configurations in karate. 
But Required request part 'inputData' not present error is coming. Is there any solution for this please?
I have attached actual input and result from karate screenshot for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that the data type of `inputData` and maybe `swaggerFile` is JSON. Looks like you are sending a string.

Please refer to this section of the doc: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

If the server does not like the `charset` being sent for each multipart, try `* configure charset = null`